# Parse JSON to get value for key

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to retrieve a value from JSON but not getting it.  It seems to have something to do with the difference between the response in the JSON and the key.  Can anyone suggest how to do this?

```
 NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            NSLog(@"Results: %@", jsonResults); 
/* This logs to console as follows:
Results: {
    code = 200;
    error = "<null>";
    response =     {
        "insert_id" = 3861;
    };
        NSLog(@"insert_id%@",[jsonResults objectForKey:@"insert_id"]);
//This logs as 
insert_id (null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output of `jsonResults`. The curly braces indicate a dictionary. And note the value of the "response" key. Its value has further curly braces. This means it is a nested dictionary.

The "insert_id" key is nested inside the "response" key's dictionary. You need:

```
NSLog(@"insert_id%@",jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"]);
```

Also note the use of modern syntax. It's easier to read and write.

Comment: Thank you!  That solved issue.  Will accept answer when it allows.

Comment: I think it's allowed now :)

Answer (score 1):

The requested value is in a nested dictionary with key `response`

```
NSLog(@"insert_id: %@",jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"]);
```